# How can I permanently authorize a google sheet for the same user?

Tags: google-apps-script, authorization

I have a google spreadsheet that has a script that queries information from the user's gmail emails and brings it into the spreadsheet. I have added a menu item to the toolbar that allows the user to run the script. When the user runs it the first time he gets the authorization message:

Authorization Required
A script attached to this document needs your permission to run.

After the script is authorized to run once it works perfectly. However, this spreadsheet is a template and I will be making multiple copies of it. The spreadsheet will only be used under my Gmail account, it is not something that I plan to distribute. Having said that, is there a way to somehow permanently authorize the script so that it does not prompt me about it every time I create a copy of the spreadsheet? I tried creating this into an addon instead of a menu item but I got the same result.

Do I have to use OAuth?

Comment: If you create an add-on, you should publish the add-on from a stand alone Apps Script file.  If the add-on code is bound to the spreadsheet that you are using as the template, then every time you copy the template spreadsheet, you'll be making a copy of the bound code also, which is a totally different Apps Script file, and therefore would be asking for authorization again.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Depending on how you are familiar with Google Apps Script, you can try to achieve that project by making a [Google Sheets Addon](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/overview). Or you can definitely build it from scratch using the Gmail API and Google Sheets API

**With a Google Apps Script**, I can see two ways of building the add-on:

1. With a [menu item in the "Add-ons" menu of the Google Sheets interface](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#createAddonMenu()). When clicked, it will trigger a Google Apps Script function that fetch information from Gmail and update the current sheet. It's all manual.
2. With a [Google Apps Script scheduler](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers), that trigger the same function (fetching from Gmail and update a sheet) on a recurrent basis (every hours, days, etc.).

**From scratch**, you can achieve the same goal without Google Apps Script. But it means that you'll have to deal with OAuth at some point (whereas GAS takes care of that for you). If you are not familiar with OAuth, I'd recommend to use Apps Script here.

Comment: Thanks for your comments and suggestions. I have opted for the " menu item in the Add-ons menu of the Google Sheets interface" option as this seems to get close to what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running into this same issue (but for a different purpose). I've published my Apps Script code (for the Sheet) as an Ad-On but there were several issues with that.

1. There were errors (I believe from improperly defined scopes) that I wasn't able to resolve.
2. Deploying as an Ad-On in my domain allows users to use it whenever they want and I only want this particular function to be used on copies of a specific template.

As it stands now, if I just scripting right in the script, the user has to Authorize on every new copy of the template. The code behind all works as expected this way. I just don't want the Authorization every time as it could be a dozen or more per day.